# C++ Windows API окно с FPS

Tags: c++, winapi, fps

Каждый раз когда я что-нибудь рисую на окне нужно вызвать Redraw для перерисовки окна. Как запустить поток обновления окна или что сделать чтобы окно перерисовывалось постоянно и имело FPS?

Comment: Надо просто постоянно его перерисовывать... И рисовать fps.

Comment: @VTT я понял) где? как?)

Comment: Да так же, как и раньше - обработали сообщения, обновили состояние приложения, перерисовали в цикле. Есть конечно более сложные сценарии, но это отдельная тема.

Comment: Какое еще перерисовывание в цикле?? Окно должен обновлять обработчик WM_PAINT, никаких дополнительных циклов или потоков там не нужно.

Comment: @freim WM_PAINT не обновляет постоянно

Comment: @freim Оконные сообщения типа WM_PAINT прокачиваются в цикле сообщений.

Comment: @Mike Waters - конечно не обновляет постоянно. Обновляет только когда нужно, и только измененный регион.@VTT - а цикл сообщений находится в главном потоке (ну, обычно). Специального потока для WM_PAINT создавать не нужно.

Comment: @freim Вот я и говорю, что надо перерисовывать в этом цикле.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас перепутаны причина и следствие. Вы пишете "Каждый раз когда я что-нибудь рисую на окне нужно вызвать Redraw для перерисовки окна", но на самом деле все происходит ровно наоборот - рисование в окне является результатом RedrawWindow (или, что чаще, результатом InvalidateRect/InvalidateRgn).

1) Когда вам необходимо обновить часть окна, вы там ничего не рисуете, а вызываете Invalidate*, объявляя часть окна требующей обновления. То же самое может сделать и Windows. Вызывать функцию RedrawWindow обычно нет необходимости, она делает то же самое, что Invalidate*, но при этом форсирует WM_PAINT. Как правило, это лучше оставить на усмотрение системы.

2) Вы должны также написать обработчик WM_PAINT, вот он и рисует все что надо. Устанавливается clipping region (чтобы не тратить времени на отрисовку не изменившихся областей), а дальше рисуете как душе угодно - со стиранием фона, через bitblt, и т.д и т.п. Этот обработчик работает в том же потоке, что и цикл сообщений (в главном потоке то есть), и вызывает его система.

Ни создавать отдельный поток отрисовки, ни перерисовывать окно постоянно не нужно. Все уже сделано грамотно и оптимально, вряд ли вам удастся как-то ускорить рисование. Если же главный поток тратит много времени на вычисления, их и нужно вынести в рабочий поток, а главный пусть и дальше занимается отрисовкой и вообще UI.

Если нужно в маленьком окошке постоянно выводить FPS или еще что, по таймеру вызывайте InvalidateRect для этого кусочка экрана, а выводите его также в обработчике WM_PAINT.

Comment: Тут стоит отметить, что `InvalidateRect` и вообще рисование именно в `WM_PAINT` имеет смысл только при использовании GDI. При использовании DXGI рисование происходит в буфере swap chain, а обновление при вызове `Present`.